# Excel distribute value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I would like to divide a number X into possibly N equal values. I explain it in the following scenario. Let's say I have 8000 copies of newspaper and they are wrapped by N (lets say 20, and this can vary). So now I have 400 packets each containing 20 paper. Assume I have X pallets. I want to distribute the 400 packets equally between the pallets where possible. Because sometimes there are more/less paletts I cannot do it with a simple divison function, in excel. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like now, and an example of desired outcome.

Comment: added picture. I also wish excel to advise me the number of palets that would be required

Comment: You would need to also know the max per pallet, in your third line, how is Excel to know you want 100,100,92 and not 98,98,96

Comment: true. If I add the max size of a palet, how can I implement it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of pallets needed Use this formula, put in B3 and copy down:

```
=ROUNDUP(A3/($B$1*$D$1),0)
```

Then to get the disbursement table, in C3:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<$B3,$D$1,IF(COLUMN(A:A)=$B3,($A3/$B$1)-(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*$D$1,""))
```

Then copy drag over and down

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps .... formulas are below each cell

[image]

Comment: This helps, but as @Scott said, I need to distribute it. based on a criteria. Thank you!

Comment: pallet can be max 100. Or I dont understand what do you mean by specify even more?

Comment: What should happen if you only had 2 pallets in the above example (i.e. more packets that the number of available pallets)?